# How can I center a menu in a responsive website? (example)

Tags: html, css, web

I am having some grave difficulty to center a silly menu on the pages of my website. I know I can set the width of an outer div to a px value, but how can I make it so it centers for a responsive website? Here's the page:

```
http://103.4.17.225/~america/index.php/product-menu/vertical-garden/gro-wall-3
```

The menu is the benefits,gallery,etc.

Thanks guys , you're the bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the float from the ul and set it to inline block;

```
.met_main_nav ul {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then use it's parent (the nav element) to center it, This will center any inline-block elements inside it (i.e the ul):

```
.met_main_nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To center horizontal menus I often use a *inline-block* approach instead of a float one, try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
.sidemen .nav { text-align: center }
.sidemen ul li {
    float: none; /* this will override your current line, just for testing */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you add the code *into* your stylesheet, you can delete your current *float* rule, and just adding the *display* one.

The menu will be centered, no mater if you resize the browser, unless you do up to extreme narrow size, in which I'd recommend using [media queries](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries) to adapt the menu rendering (reducing the margin or adapting styles to show in two lines perhaps).